# How to implement a expression builder in C++/QT which is similar to Microsoft TFS query builder?

Tags: c++, qt, query-builder

In Microsoft TFS, there is a query builder as follow:
[image]

And I'm requested to implement a feature just like TFS query builder in C++/QT. But I don't even know how to google it.

Basically, with this feature, user will be able to set the condition to execute a specific action when our app running. eg:

```
// the condition will be set by user before run this application
// and I want provide a UI similar to TFS query to user
if (var_a >= 0 && (var_b + var_c) < 10) 
{
   prompt the warning dialog
}
```

this condition `(var_a >= 0 && (var_b + var_c) < 10)` will be stored as xml as below:

```
<ConditionPair Operator="AND">
    <Condition Operator="GE">
        <LValue>
            <Kind>Variable</Kind>
            <Value>var_a</Value>
        </LValue>
        <RValue>
            <Kind>Const</Kind>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </RValue>
    </Condition>
    <Condition Operator="LT">
        <LValue>
            <Kind>Expression</Kind>
            <Value>
                <MathExp Operator="ADD">
                    <LValue>
                        <Kind>Variable</Kind>
                        <Value>var_b</Value>
                    </LValue>
                    <RValue>
                        <Kind>Variable</Kind>
                        <Value>var_c</Value>
                    </RValue>
                </MathExp>
            </Value>
        </LValue>
        <RValue>
            <Kind>Const</Kind>
            <Value>10</Value>
        </RValue>
    </Condition>
</ConditionPair>
```

I know how to implement the UI, but I DO NOT know how to interpret the expression.

**Is there any open source library or blog about this topic available online?**

Any thoughts about this is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to generate SQL for this so that you can query a database in Qt?

Comment: @drescherjm No, nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: How is the data organized?  Why is it not in a database?

Comment: It's not about query data. I have a internal key-value store in my app (the value of each key may be updated by external app via RPC call). When running, my app should evaluate all these custom defined expressions every second, and do the assigned action according to the eval result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if I've understood you, but maybe you could use [Qt Script](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscript-index.html)
to interpret (parse) the commands and then act.